# Doubling the domain in a power function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So this a pre-calculus question from an online course I'm taking. I already have the answer but trying to understand the algebra.

Give the power function:

$P(r) =Cr^a$

It was explained that "if r doubles, $P(r)$ changes by a factor $2^a$".

Then these steps were given:

"if we look at a certain $r$, and then we double $r$ to $2r$, then $P(2r)=C(2r)^a=Cr^a⋅2a=P(r)⋅2^a$"

I don't understand the algebra steps above, can anyone explain them a little easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $P(r) = C r^a$ we have

$$P(2r) = C (2r)^a = C \cdot (2^a \cdot r^a) = \color {red}{(C \cdot r^a)} \cdot 2^a = \color{red}{P(r)} \cdot 2^a$$

Then if you haven't written anything wrong, there is typo on the second equality, it should be $2^a$ instead of $2a$.